# Vlook up not giving correct results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

[image]

Hi, i have two ID columns , ID and ID2. ID has 127 rows. ID 2 has 180. I want to use a V look up to see what id's from id are in id2. there should be 127 ID's in 1d2 (180 Id's) However when i use the v look up formula  `=VLOOKUP(A3,B3:B127,1,FALSE)`, it only gives 40 id's in id 2 which is wrong. when i change it to `=VLOOKUP(A3,B3:B127,2,FALSE)`, to get the exact column number im looking for column 2 , it gives #REF! error or NA error and nothing shows up. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to try semi-absolute referencing `=VLOOKUP(A3,B$3:B$127,1,FALSE)`. If that does not help then you simply don't have identical ID's (possible trailing characters?) Also the `#REF!` error on your 2nd attempt is because `B3:B27` holds just a single column hence you can't reference the 2nd column.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem in your formula is Absolute Reference

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,$B$3:B127,1,FALSE)
```

Use this formula and drag it down

Comment: its still the same result. it gives 80 matches between id and id2. when i highlight the two columns to see the duplicate values in each of the 2 columns, 121 rows are highlighted in id1 meaning their duplicate value must be in id2, this is what i don't understand

Comment: Its giving normal results from my side, could you please share your data screen shots.

Comment: How many matches did you get for IDs in ID1 in ID2?

Comment: I just made 10 results with duplicate ids for testing purpose

Comment: Can i send you the file via email , i can't understand what is going on . when i highlight column 1 (id2) for duplicate values , it shows none meaning all values in column 1 are unique. then when i do the same for column 2 (id) it shows no duplicate values again meaning all values for column 2 are unique. Then when i highlight both columns to look for duplicate values , it shows 127 rows in both columns to be highlighted as duplicates meaning there is 127 rows that are present in column 1 that are also in column 2. so i expect the v look up to return 127, however, it only returns 80?

Comment: i used the exact formula you mentioned for the v look up

Comment: Yes, You can check my profile (About Section) for contact purpose. I would love to guide you how to sort your problem out.